# Internet Explorer negative margin not working as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margins, overlapping, margin

The guy who created the website for my church said there is no way to fix the issue and that we shouldn't worry about it. But I think he's wrong and I'm attempting to fix it myself. My coding background is in C++ and Cobol but not really in CSS. I'm learning though, so any help here would be great.

The site uses Joomla and is here: http://www.anointedesign.com/mtvernon/site2/

It looks good in Firefox and Chrome but in Internet Explorer there is a huge gap at the top between the top header box and the slide show. I believe this is an IE issue in the way it handles negative margin values but I may be way off here and need help.

The entire top nav, logo and seal should be very close to the slide show, to the point where the left seal should overlap the slide show by about 15px.

Comment: Yup it's because of these errors that you have the negative margin not working properly. You have div's and they are closed with />. Once you fix these errors, I am sure it will turn out ok in IE too as it looks in FF, GG, AS and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

This css code will fix it:

```
#horiz-menu {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: -110px;
}

#header-bg > div.wrapper {
clear: both;
}

#showcase-section {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

The problem is caused by floats and clears inside the horiz-menu div. IE doesn't like divs with that kind of CSS code. :)